# XAMPP inside VM on VM Server

Tags: networking, xampp, esxi

I've got an IBM-Server inside my Network (IP= 192.168.178.10, running on ESXI 5.5)<

Inside this host, I've got 3 VMs running (IPs = 192.168.178.97 - 192.168.178.99, Each Windows Server 2012)

Inside these VMs I've got XAMPP Apache Servers running.
My question is:

How do I make the XAMPP pages visible to the home network? Because every time I open the IPs inside my browser of my laptop (IP = 192.168.178.26), Chrome says that the Server is unavailable.

Strangely - If I type exactly same IP inside the browser of one VM, I can open the pages...
I can also access my Laptop XAMPP Server from inside the VM.

Comment: Those are some pretty odd IPs.  Where did they come from?

Comment: @Charles: These are just the internal IPs. In my case: 192.168.178.xxx

Comment: Ah, okay.  You should be explicit about that kind of thing, for clarity.  Can you access the IP of other VMs from within one of the VMs?

Comment: @Charles: no, I can't access one VM from inside an other VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I found the solution myself:

Apache seems to have opened the ports in the firewall, but somehow windows partly blocked the network communication - don't ask me how exactly, but I solved the problem by resetting the firewall, windows network settings and apache/xampp